# Inheritance recursion

Tags: c#, wpf

So I tried to implement some inheritance into my code because I have many classes that require the same instances of other classes which I pass as parameters, but now I encounter a recursion problem which I don't quite understand why.

It breaks in the ParentScreen class (which is just a normal class, no XAML) - maybe this isnt the best way to solve my simple problem?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ParentScreen ps = new ParentScreen();
        container.Children.Add(ps.ms);
    }
}

public class ParentScreen : UserControl
{
    public MainScreen ms;

    public ParentScreen()
    {
        ms = new MainScreen(); // breaks here
    }
}

public partial class MainScreen : ParentScreen
{
    public MainScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<runtime:ParentScreen x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainScreen"
        xmlns:runtime="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        Height="100" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</runtime:ParentScreen>
```

Comment: When creating a parentScreen object your code calls the constructor which creates a mainScreen object. As MainScreen object inherits from ParentScreen - you just create a new parentScreen object, and therefore call, once again parentScreen constructor! -> StackoverflowExcepetion?!

Comment: Oh so I do... oops! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You'd need to 'rephrase' the solution (and the problem) a bit - i.e. that's not the happiest way to handle reuse with WPF user controls and for one reason or another you'll end up with problems. This was just an obvious bug :), but you could get into more trouble, harder to spot. And inheritance isn't the best choice for GUI/WPF components, and in WPF case that doesn't smell best. Around WPF you're best to try and implement things via MVVM and e.g. data templates for various controls - and resort to custom coding controls only as a last resort - that'd help you, guide you towards.best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 problems:

- You're mixing "Instance" and "class" concept
  When A inherit B, and you instanciate a new A then you only have one instance of A , not 2 instance (A & B)
- When inheriting and you put a default CTor, the base CTor is automatically called. Which means this code:

  public partial class MainScreen : ParentScreen
  {
      public MainScreen()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }
  }

Is the same than:

```
public partial class MainScreen : ParentScreen
{
    public MainScreen() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

so when you call

```
ParentScreen ps = new ParentScreen();
```

What happend:

- ParentScreen.CTor =>  ms = new MainScreen();
- MainScreen.CTor => ParentScreen.CTor (because MainScreen inherit from
  ParentScreen) =>  ms = new MainScreen();
- MainScreen.CTor => ParentScreen.CTor
- ParentScreen.CTor  =>  ms = new MainScreen();

etc (infinite loo)

Answer (score 0):

It should be a stackoverflowException?

When you create a sub-class, first it will call its parent-class's constructor.

```
using System;

class Parent
{
  private Client m_client;
  public Parent()
  {
    m_client = new Client();
    Console.WriteLine("client inited");
  }
}

class Client: Parent
{
  public Client()
  {
    //..
  }
}

class Test
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Client c = new Client();
    Console.WriteLine("End");
  }
}
```

run the code above, it will cause un Segment Error on Mono runs on MacOS.

Check it what happen in windows.

:)